# How to effectively process binary files served from ftp and store results on GCS

Tags: apache-spark, ftp, flume, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I need to download about 2 millions of gunzip files from ftp server (not sftp), process them and store results (jpeg images) on google cloud storage.
I have considered to spin a dataproc cluster, then get files from ftp and process with Spark. But not sure how well Spark will handle these binary files.

Could someone please suggest a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: How large / small are the gzipped files? Spark has a built-in SparkContext.binaryFiles method, but it is best for smaller files.

Comment: @AngusDavis files are about 100KB to 10MB. Is that considered small/big?

Comment: 10MB is probably getting into 'not quite small' territory, but it's still worth a shot to see what happens (I could see there being excess shuffle / poorly balanced partitions, depending on how things shake out, but should be fairly trivial run a test). Something to consider is breaking this into two steps: step 1) distcp from ftp to GCS and step 2) process files from GCS. It might make experimentation less expensive by reducing FTP operations.